# Check Signuatures

Tags: vb.net, digital-signature, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I'm trying to check the signature of some "Signed" Files, specifically the Microsoft TrustedInstaller.exe. Currently I'm trying on Windows 7 (64 bit) with the latest updates.

I downloaded the sysinternal tool [sigcheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441) ran the command and got "good" information

```
    Verified:       Signed
    Signing date:   2:37 PM 11/20/2010
    Publisher:      Microsoft Windows
    Company:        Microsoft Corporation
    Description:    Windows Modules Installer
    Product:        Microsoft« Windows« Operating System
    Prod version:   6.1.7601.17514
    File version:   6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
    MachineType:    64-bit
```

I tried the follow code

```
Public Function CheckSign(Path As String) As String

    Dim filePath As String = Path

    If Not File.Exists(filePath) Then
        Console.WriteLine("File not found")
        Return "File Not Found"
    End If

    Dim theCertificate As X509Certificate2

    Try
        Dim theSigner As X509Certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(filePath)
        theCertificate = New X509Certificate2(theSigner)
    Catch ex As Exception
          Return "Not Signed"
    End Try

    Dim chainIsValid As Boolean = False

    Dim theCertificateChain = New X509Chain(True)

    theCertificateChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot
    theCertificateChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Offline
    theCertificateChain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
    theCertificateChain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag

    chainIsValid = theCertificateChain.Build(theCertificate)


    Dim doTrust As Boolean = (theCertificateChain.ChainElements(theCertificateChain.ChainElements.Count - 1).Certificate.Verify)
    If doTrust = False Then
        Console.WriteLine("WE DO NOT TRUST THEM ")
        Console.WriteLine("Publisher Information : " + theCertificate.SubjectName.Name)
        Return "No Trust"
    End If

    Return "Trusted"

End Function
```

Which works for most things, but it turns out that some files (like the trustedinstaller @ C:\windows\servicing\trustedinstaller.exe ) it comes back as "Not Signed" meaning that the its throwing the following error

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Cannot find the requested object.

Any idea how I can check the signature of all files, not just "most" (like the code above does or any ideas why this is failing ?

Comment: the code looks ok. `TrustedInstaller.exe` is not authenticode signed.

Comment: sigcode ... finds a signature, how do I check for that type of signature or do you know what type of signature TrustedInstaller uses ?

Comment: Take properties of the file and there will be no Digital Signature tab. I suspect sigcode uses catalog signing to validate signature.